# NullReferenceException using Where() in AutoMapper.MapFrom

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper, automapper-8

I'm modelling a 3rd party database using Automapper 8 and EF 6.
One of my DTO classes needs to use a `Where` clause on an association to locate the correct record.

```
// Community table is mapped and working.
// Mapping breaks when mapping dest.Subjects
cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
    // snip many mappings
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id,       act => act.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Community.NetworkLogin))
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Subjects,
        act => act.MapFrom(
            src => src.Community.StudentClasses.Where(
                subject => subject.Year == CurrentSemester.Year && subject.Semester == CurrentSemester.Semester)))
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Contacts,
        act => act.MapFrom(
            src => src.Community.Contacts.Where(
                contact => Contact.UseThis).Select(contact => contact.ContactDetails)));
```

This code works in production, but I'd really like to Unit Test this model. Running a simple test (get all records in the Mock) I'm hit with a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to access the `Community.StudentClasses` object.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240089/why-is-automapper-projectto-throwing-a-null-reference-exception) relating to `NullReferenceException`exceptions and AutoMapper, which helped me fix the rest of the references in this config, but I'm still having issues with this one. The test works when I remove the `Community.StudentClasses` mapping.

I'm mocking objects using code similar to:

```
public static Person Person19788 =>
    new SchoolContact
    {
        ID                                      = 19788,
        NetworkLogin                            = "username",
        // Tried various creation methods
        // StudentClasses  = new List<StudentClass> {new StudentClass()},
        // StudentClasses = new List<StudentClass> {new StudentClass {Year = 0, Semester = 0}},
        StudentClasses = null,
        StudentContacts = null,
        Address         = Address19788
    };
```

`CurrentSemester` has been checked, and returns valid non-zero values for `Year` and `Semester`.

The strange thing is that the `Contacts` mapping works fine, even with `null` values. So I assume that I've broken my Subjects mapping somewhere along the line, but I'm unsure where else to look.

Comment: Your tests are too far from the real thing, hence your issues. You should use a real database or at least an in memory database.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem **was** with my `Subjects` mapping after all.
The top-level associations were mapped correctly, however the lower-level associations were not. (I didn't include these mappings because a) I didn't think about them, and b) there's only so much code that anyone would be willing to wade through).

After fixing up the `w > x > y > z` mappings everything is working as expected. I thought I'd exhausted all options before posting this question. Lesson learned: don't post to SO until you've slept on it and taken a fresh look at the code the next day.